# 5 random numbers, first number not zero

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops, random

I have a code which produces 5 unique random numbers between 0-9. However I don't want the first number to be zero.

How do I solve this?

```
var arr = []
while(arr.length < 5){
    var randomnumber = Math.floor(Math.random()*10);
    if(arr.indexOf(randomnumber) > -1) continue;
    arr[arr.length] = randomnumber;
}
document.write(arr);
```

Comment: just add `1`....

Comment: Well, it's not duplicate... `:)`

Answer (score 0):

It's very simple, **as your numbers don't get repeated**. If first number is `0`, just swap it with a value of random index. Here I have used index `3`.

```js
var arr = []
while (arr.length < 5) {
  var randomnumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * 10);
  if (arr.indexOf(randomnumber) > -1) continue;
  arr[arr.length] = randomnumber;
}
if (arr[0] === 0) {
  arr[0] = arr[3];
  arr[3] = 0;
}
console.log(arr);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {top: 0; height: 100%;}
```

Testing to create 100 different cases:

```js
var all = [];
var arr = [];
for (var i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
  arr = [];
  while (arr.length < 5) {
    var randomnumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * 10);
    if (arr.indexOf(randomnumber) > -1) continue;
    arr[arr.length] = randomnumber;
  }
  if (arr[0] === 0) {
    arr[0] = arr[3];
    arr[3] = 0;
  }
  all.push(arr.join(", "));
}
console.log(all);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {top: 0; height: 100%;}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could insert a check for a zero at start and continue.

```js
var array = [],
    randomnumber;

while (array.length < 5) {
    randomnumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * 10);
    if (array.indexOf(randomnumber) > -1 || !array.length && !randomnumber) continue;
    array.push(randomnumber);
}

console.log(array);
```